# How to make blinking vertical text cursor/marker more pronounced

Tags: mac, text, cursor

I am writing a Master Thesis on my Mac. Unfortunately I have to use MS Word. The blinking vertical marker that shows where I am writing is not pronounced enough sometimes when there is a wall of text, which sometimes when I change something in the previous paragraph make it hard to find it.

I would like to change the text cursor, make it bigger, add some color to it, whatever that makes it more pronounced. Is it possible without changing whole cursor?

Thanks

Comment: What version of macOS, and which version of Word?

Comment: Monterey and 365, the newest possible

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Monterey, change the mouse pointer in the Accessibility preference pane.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a way to just change the text marker, the pointer is fine.